# Website size dramatically changes in browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, size

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question and I just don't realize it, but I designed a site for a client that I hoped would fit in the browser, eliminating the need for a scrollbar. I know that it's impossible that one size would fit all computers, and I designed it so it would fit my type of monitor (1024x768) and I took into account that the browser's frame takes up space too, etc.

Here's the issue: when I pulled in all my pictures that I saved out from photoshop (sized correctly from the mockup) it all became a little bigger in the browser (Firefox, latest version) and is just a smidge too large, so it cuts off the very bottom and has a scrollbar for that tiny amount of space.

Even weirder still, in Chrome everything gets really small. I've tested this out on multiple computers and even had my friends check. Only one person didn't see as huge of a difference as I got, but still saw it was slightly smaller in Chrome. Both browsers are set to 100% zoom.

Here's the site: http://dinneronthespot.com/index2.html

So basically I have two questions: Why is it bigger than my design? I looked up sizes and everything before I started the mockup. And why is Chrome shrinking everything?

Thanks for you're help!! I've made sites before, but I'm definitely not an expert...

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdinneronthespot.com%2Findex2.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: I've used the validator, nothing wrong that would cause this...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ctrl + 0 to reset viewing in chrome?

( and: ctrl plus is zooming in,
ctrl minus is zooming out)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your zoom factor against your friend's zoom factor (both need to be of the same amount, typically 100%).

You can't suppose the right dimensions, even if you try to consider the toolbar (i.e. even on the same browser, each user could have really different toolbar height).

Try to use [responsive layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) in case like this.

Comment: Every browser I've checked in is 100% zoom, I double checked this today, which is why it's so baffling.

I usually like responsive layouts, but my client specifically wanted a fixed kind for various reasons...